# how to validate http response code in soundcloud php api?

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I tried with the following code but it displayed an error that said:

CODE:

```
if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $soundcloud->_validResponseCode($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $soundcloud->accessToken($_GET['code']);
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

ERROR:

```
 Fatal error: Call to protected method Services_Soundcloud::_validResponseCode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch block and then get the http code from the exception, par example:

```
// check the status of the relationship
try {
    $client->get('/me/followings/3207');
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getHttpCode() == '404')
        print "You are not following user 3207\n";
}
```

Comment: what I'm trying to do here is to validate the code that is returned after I connect to soundcloud... in the callback page...

Comment: @Tej I think you are to assume it is fine, unless an exception is thrown, nothing has gone wrong. You cannot access the httpcode/responsecode properties/methods because they are private/protected